# VuePress not hot reloading, but does when config.js is changed

Tags: vuepress

I'm using VuePress for the first time, and updating `.md` files isn't triggering live reloading.

If I update the `.vuepress/config.js` my browser does reload. If I run:

```
vuepress dev --debug
```

I see this line in the output, which seems suspicious:

```
debug watchFiles [
  '.vuepress/config.js',
  '.vuepress/config.yml',
  '.vuepress/config.toml'
]
```

Is this the error, or is this correct? Googling `vuepress watchfiles` doesn't show anything particularly useful.

Comment: There are some problems with Vuepress hot reload. That's why the Evan You is creating [Vite](https://github.com/vitejs/vite) and doing tests with [Vitepress](https://github.com/vuejs/vitepress) (Vuepress repository for tests)

Answer (score 0):

There is an [issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vuepress/issues/221) discussed in the repository, which hints at a possible problem cause.

A broken connection error may be fixed with hard-refreshing the page. Modifying the templates and the content pages reloads after that.

Check the browser console to see what the actual issue is.

Some actions require manual restart. For example, renaming the template files or adding components will cause an error. Changing the config file also does not trigger the reload.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to config.js

```
module.exports = {
  host: 'localhost',
...
```

Answer (score 0):

just delete the those folders and run again.

```
.vuepress/.cache
.vuepress/.temp
```